# jQuery function queueing confusion

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to understand exactly what it means when I put multiple calls in a row on jQuery, because I'm not getting the results I expect in similar situations.

Example 1:

```
$(this).animate({opacity: 0.25}, 250).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 250);
```

As expected, this gives a quick flash of translucency before returning to full opacity.

Example 2:

```
$(this).animate({opacity: 0.25}, 250).removeAttr("style");
```

In this case, instead of a gradual return to opacity, I would expect the removeAttr("style") to cause it to jump back to opacity after the animation is complete. This is because the animate opacity function merely changes values for `opacity` and sets `display:block`, and I would expect that by removing these styles, everything returns to normal.

Instead, it seems like the removeAttr is firing before the animation is complete, clears out the style, and then animation sets the opacity some more, leaving the item translucent.

The fact that this is the sequence of events would seem to be confirmed by the fact that altering the removeAttr to use a completion callback works properly:

```
$(this).animate({opacity: 0.25}, 250, function(){$(this).removeAttr("style");});
```

**Why is it that animations appear to be processed serially, while at least some functions are processed in parallel with the animations?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different queues at work here.

When you call `animate`, it is pushed onto the effects queue, called `fx`. Most other things don't use a queue. This is why the two calls seem to happen both at once.

Comment: +1, but most of the other functions such as `removeAttr()` don't even use a queue, but apply their effects immediately.

Comment: @Box9: I was just going to edit my answer :), after playing around a while with jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QVXEC/

Comment: By changing `queue` to `false` on the call to `animate`, it should execute immediately without waiting for other functions on the `fx` queue. And it does, but it doesn't quite execute synchronously as one would be lead to believe, since `removeAttr` fires immediately as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat `animate` as asynchronous.

If you want something to happen *after* the animation finishes then you should use callback functions.